# Angular $injector errors when scripts are "dynamically" loaded

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm running into an issue when I dynamically load scripts on to a page. Currently we have two separate projects, one SharePoint application and one "CDN" website where we host all of our content files (js, css, images, etc...).

Due to the fact that these are separated out into multiple projects we had to get creative with the way we loaded scripts (making sure that if we're browsing around our Sharepoint project's dev environment it loads content from the CDN's dev environment)

Here's the script we use to dynamically load the script tags:

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var ReferenceLoader = (function () {
            var cdnUrl = {
                'devSPDomain': 'https://devCDN/',
                'testSPDomain': 'https://testCDN/',
                'prodSPDomain': 'https://prodCDN/'
            },
            baseUrl = cdnUrl[window.location.host] || 'https://prodCDN/';

            this.InsertReference = function (sources, type) {
                sources = [].concat(sources); // make sure it's an array
                type = type || 'script'; // default to script

                switch (type.toLowerCase()) {
                    case 'script': InsertScriptReference(sources); break;
                    case 'style': InsertStyleReference(sources); break;
                    default: console.log('Invalid type supplied to \'InsertReference()\'');
                }
            };

            function InsertScriptReference(sources) {
                for (var i = 0; i < sources.length; i++) {
                    var s = document.createElement('script'),
                        src = baseUrl + sources[i];

                    s.setAttribute('type', 'text/javascript');
                    s.setAttribute('src', src);

                    document.head.appendChild(s);
                }
            }

            function InsertStyleReference(sources) {
                for (var i = 0; i < sources.length; i++) {
                    var s = document.createElement('style'),
                        src = baseUrl + sources[i];

                    s.setAttribute('rel', 'stylesheet');
                    s.setAttribute('href', src);

                    document.head.appendChild(s);
                }
            }

            return this;
        })();
    </script>
```

And then on any given page we use it like so:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var scripts = [
        'dist/js/plugins/chart/0.0.1/chart.min.js',
        'dist/js/shared/services/util/0.0.1/utilServices.min.js',
        'dist/js/components/home/0.0.4/home.min.js'
    ];

    ReferenceLoader.InsertReference(scripts);
</script>
```

Now this all works great, I can see on the page where it's successfully putting the script/link tags in the head element, however I'm getting an [angular injector error](https://docs.angularjs.org/error/$injector/modulerr?p0=app.home&p1=Error:%20%5B$injector:nomod%5D%20http:%2F%2Ferrors.angularjs.org%2F1.3.14%2F$injector%2Fnomod%3Fp0%3Dapp.home%0A%20%20%20%20at%20Error%20(native)%0A%20%20%20%20at%20https:%2F%2Fajax.googleapis.com%2Fajax%2Flibs%2Fangularjs%2F1.3.14%2Fangular.min.js:6:417%0A%20%20%20%20at%20https:%2F%2Fajax.googleapis.com%2Fajax%2Flibs%2Fangularjs%2F1.3.14%2Fangular.min.js:21:412%0A%20%20%20%20at%20a%20(https:%2F%2Fajax.googleapis.com%2Fajax%2Flibs%2Fangularjs%2F1.3.14%2Fangular.min.js:21:53)%0A%20%20%20%20at%20https:%2F%2Fajax.googleapis.com%2Fajax%2Flibs%2Fangularjs%2F1.3.14%2Fangular.min.js:21:296%0A%20%20%20%20at%20https:%2F%2Fajax.googleapis.com%2Fajax%2Flibs%2Fangularjs%2F1.3.14%2Fangular.min.js:35:46%0A%20%20%20%20at%20s%20(https:%2F%2Fajax.googleapis.com%2Fajax%2Flibs%2Fangularjs%2F1.3.14%2Fangular.min.js:7:302)%0A%20%20%20%20at%20g%20(https:%2F%2Fajax.googleapis.com%2Fajax%2Flibs%2Fangularjs%2F1.3.14%2Fangular.min.js:34:399)%0A%20%20%20%20at%20ab%20(https:%2F%2Fajax.googleapis.com%2Fajax%2Flibs%2Fangularjs%2F1.3.14%2Fangular.min.js:38:135)%0A%20%20%20%20at%20d%20(https:%2F%2Fajax.googleapis.com%2Fajax%2Flibs%2Fangularjs%2F1.3.14%2Fangular.min.js:17:381). I'm 110% positive the file with the module in it is being loaded and if instead I just do a normal script tag that points directly to it on my page (in the head or body), it works fine. Any ideas?

Here's a [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/BXBL4hUftL1da3I9ECtH?p=preview) displaying the issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up fixing this by doing two things:

- Adding a callback parameter to the InsertReference that is called as the .onload/.onreadystatechanged event of the element so that each time a script is **finished** loading it executes
- Removing the ng-app tag from the aplication and manually bootstrapping it once all the script files were done loading

Answer (score 0):

I think the way you're requesting the files is good, however the injection error is probably generated because of the minified files.
You must use the Minification-safe controller declaration:

```
var myController = function(anyVariableName, $http) {
  //We included $scope and the $http service into our controller.
  //Since we set up the $inject attribute on our controller, it doesn't matter what variable names we use.
}

myController.$inject = ['$scope', '$http']
```

Have a look here: http://thegreenpizza.github.io/2013/05/25/building-minification-safe-angular.js-applications/

Comment: Unfortunately that's not it, everything is properly minified.